# Compare length of strings within list items

Tags: jquery

please help me with a simple problem in jQuery. I have a load of list items on a page and I need to compare the length of the strings within them. If they are greater than 100 characters then I need to add a class to the 'li' otherwise nothing happens. 
My code so far:

```
<ul id="mylist">
     <li>This is a string with more than 100 characters in it. This is a string with more                than 100 characters in it.</li>
   <li>This is a string with less than 100</li>
 </ul>

  var len = $("#mylist li").text().length;
    $( "#mylist li" ).each(function() {
    if (len > 100) {
           $(this).addClass("test");
    }
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work. Put your length check inside the loop:

```
$("#mylist li").each(function(e,el) {
    var intLen = $(el).text().length;
    if (intLen > 100) {
           $(this).addClass("test");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the text of each li like this

```
$('#mylist li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().length > 100) {
        $(this).addClass("test");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$( "#mylist li" ).each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().length> 100) {
       $(this).addClass("test");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = $("#mylist li").text().length;
```

The above code will make use of *entire `li`'s text* (ie., Total no. of characters within the `mylist li`'s).  Hence it is not working.

So keep it inside the each method to check for individual `li`s.

```
$( "#mylist li" ).each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length > 100) {  //individual li 
           $(this).addClass("test");
    }
```

Comment: They were all correct answers but I accepted Praveens because he told me where my error was. Appreciated all the answers...